# Click event is not being triggered - jQuery

Tags: jquery

```
$(document).on('click', 'a', function(){
    e.preventDefault();
    alert(yes);
});

<a href="#" class="button is-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-id="modal-create-news" style="background-color: #262331 !important;"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>&nbsp; Create Announcement</a>
```

Once I click the button the page only refreshes, so the click event is not being triggered, not sure why.

Comment: do you get any error in console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add your Jquery CDN and also you need to declare local variable 'e' in function.And even yes is not declared as variable. I guess it is to test alert.So i put it as a String.

```js
$(document).on('click', 'a', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    alert("yes");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" class="button is-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-id="modal-create-news" style="background-color: #262331 !important;"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>&nbsp; Create Announcement</a>
```